# Getting the point on a scatter chart with TimeSeries

Tags: achartengine

After zooming or panning a scatter chart with a TimeSeries, the pointIndex points is calculated based on what is on the screen.

If there are 10 items in a series, when the chart is first show, item 1 is at pointIndex 0. Item 2 is at pointIndex 1, etc. However, once you zoom or pan, then the pointIndex starts with what is SHOWN, not the index of the item in the series.

Has anyone figured out a way to get the series index value of the point and not the panned/zoomed index value?

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out by changing the method of **XYSeries** named **getRange**.

```
public synchronized RangeHolderWithDiff getRange(double start, double stop,
  boolean beforeAfterPoints) {
int diff = 0;
if (beforeAfterPoints) {
  // we need to add one point before the start and one point after the end
  // (if
  // there are any)
  // to ensure that line doesn't end before the end of the screen

  // this would be simply: start = mXY.lowerKey(start) but NavigableMap is
  // available since API 9
  SortedMap<Double, Double> headMap = mXY.headMap(start);
  if (!headMap.isEmpty()) {
    start = headMap.lastKey();
    diff = headMap.size();
    System.out.println("DIFF IS " + diff);
  }

  // this would be simply: end = mXY.higherKey(end) but NavigableMap is
  // available since API 9
  // so we have to do this hack in order to support older versions
  SortedMap<Double, Double> tailMap = mXY.tailMap(stop);
  if (!tailMap.isEmpty()) {
    Iterator<Double> tailIterator = tailMap.keySet().iterator();
    Double next = tailIterator.next();
    if (tailIterator.hasNext()) {
      stop = tailIterator.next();
    } else {
      stop += next;
    }
  }
}
RangeHolderWithDiff mRangeHolderWithDiff = new RangeHolderWithDiff();
mRangeHolderWithDiff.indexDiff = diff;
mRangeHolderWithDiff.sortedMap = mXY.subMap(start, stop);
return mRangeHolderWithDiff;
```

}

the diff variable gives you extra x Value count , i am trying to add this parameter to touchAreas. If i can do that i will edit my answer. good luck.